# need to prevent a submit if form has not changed

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, form-submit

I have a form :

```
<form action = "person2.cfm"
    id       = "pers2form" 
    name     = "pers2form"
    method   = "post"
    style    = "dislay: inline-block; margin:auto"
    onsubmit = "return pers1()">
```

...stuff ...

```
  <input type  = "Submit"
      name  = "subpers2"
      id    = "subpers2" 
      class = "submitbut"
      style = "display: block; margin:10px auto 10px auto"
      value = "Submit">

</form>
```

When it is submitted it gets to person2.cfm, which immediately includes it, and restores the values that were input, so the user can see what he entered, and change it if it is wrong.

However, if he does not change it, and hits the submit button a second time, bad things happen.  So I want to find a way to prevent a 2nd submit.  I have put an event listener in the onsubmit script pers1().

```
var q = 'no';
var form = document.getElementById("pers2form");
form.addEventListener("input", function () {
 q = 'yes';
 });
```

with the hope that if there is no input, q will be set to yes, and I can return false.  However, q is never set to yes, no matter what.  I've tried the listener for a "click" event as well, but q is still "no" regardless.

Can anyone suggest a way I can prevent a second submit in absence of any change to the form?

Comment: you have to put evenet lister on input not form

Comment: What sort of bad things happen?

Comment: Dan, the form transmits another copy of each input and then they are doubled.  For example, if it originally transmitted "Betty" and then hit submit again, it becomes "Betty,Betty".   Not what is meant.

Comment: Hermant -- I'll give it a try.  Back to you next week.

Comment: I may have misdiagnosed the problem, as I have an earlier version which is working fine without this issue.  I'll be comparing the old and new versions to see what changed.  Will report back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has mentioned that she may have misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: It sounds like on your first submit, you are maybe passing the form values and saving them outside of the form. Then when you submit the second time, it's submitting the passed values from Submit 1 and then the values from the form for Submit 2. If you need to do them like this, just return them directly into the form and don't have the values saved twice.

Comment: Shawn -- how do you "return them directly into the form"?  I'm sending them back from the target .cmf using javascript.